# Request a Mass Deletion

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I would like an admin or moderator to delete some of my questions.
These questions were asked when I was just starting out at my development:

- [Create a Compiler for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156363/create-a-compiler-for-windows)
- [Downloading file using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114658/download-file-using-c)
- [Best editor for C++ development under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148740/best-editor-for-c-development-under-windows)
- [Is PythonCE good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172173/is-pythonce-good-closed)
- [Is C# a versatile language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554779/is-c-a-versatile-language-closed)
- [Game Boy visual games development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150048/game-boy-visual-games-development-closed)
- [Best language to start!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089509/best-language-to-start-closed)
- [To development what is the best: Windows or Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171602/to-development-what-is-the-best-windows-or-linux-closed)
- [Good free forum hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172384/good-free-forum-hosting-closed)
- [Is SmallTalk "Dead"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634605/is-smalltalk-dead-closed)
- [How do I get email content from Mail::Message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608420/how-do-i-get-the-email-content-from-mailmessage)
- [Issue regarding size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217910/issue-regarding-sizet)
- [Do a code injection in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219029/do-a-code-injection-in-c-closed)
- [Read something after a word in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215688/read-something-after-a-word-in-c)
- [Install CDT plug-in on Eclipse Ganymede](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150072/install-cdt-plug-in-on-eclipse-ganymede)
- [Making a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114667/making-a-makefile)
- [Free svn hosting server without project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147616/free-svn-hosting-server-without-project)
- [What was the biggest thing you've done in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683171/what-was-the-biggest-thing-that-youve-done-in-r-closed)
- [What can I do with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677164/what-i-can-do-with-r)
- [.NET runtime optimization service is turning my system unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670710/net-runtime-optimization-service-is-turning-my-system-unstable)

**I just want to start a new life here. I want to delete these horrible questions.**

Comment: Why not just spend a little time to clean them up?

Comment: If you're that worried about it, why not start a new account?

Comment: Embrace them! You are learning from your mistakes. Keeping them would show a strengthened personality.

Comment: You can do it yourself, go to "start" -> "run" -> enter 'cmd' and type 'format c:\'

Comment: Ignoring whether or not you should request this at all, this would be better done by emailing team@stackoverflow.com instead of airing it all out here on meta.

Answer (score 16):

One issue here is that sometimes there are very good answers to... "wanting" questions. And perhaps somebody else might have a similar question and benefit from them?

Personally I'd say keep them and wear them as battle scars. A second best might be to somehow detach them from your account... Jeff?

Comment: there is no good way to do this, we'd have to manually manipulate the database for every post. So the answer is probably No.

Answer (score 9):

*"These questions were asked when I was just starting out at"*

Some of them (like [What Was The Biggest Thing That You’ve Done In R? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683171/what-was-the-biggest-thing-that-youve-done-in-r-closed) and [What I Can Do With R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677164/what-i-can-do-with-r)) were asked within the last two days. Seems you're making rapid progress.

Answer (score 4):

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690262/how-can-i-create-a-soap-header-like-this) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729303/does-the-gpl-license-contaminate) [stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797147/why-can-i-sort-an-inline-select-value-but-not-use-it-in-a-where-clause) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155260/what-is-the-functionality-within-c) [feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666272/matching-fixed-format-numbers-in-regex) [stupid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487052/moving-a-system-from-sort-of-a-class-system-to-an-mvc-format) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379231/how-is-gui-and-game-program-flow-compared-to-web-programs) [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282829/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-console-games-than-with-console-clear), but as Marc stated, other people might have similar issues and get the great help I got back in the day.

I'm smarter now, and looking back on these questions, I often ask myself "what was I thinking" but I'm proud of them, since without them, I wouldn't be the person I am today.

Comment: Your "stupid" questions have no downvotes like his ones. But I can fix that for you, if you want :)

Comment: If that's what you feel, go for it :) I don't mind. Vikings can take anything!

Comment: I love vikings! They don't whine :)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you delete them yourself? I thought there was a delete button on questions.

Incidentally recently I answered somebody's question about binary coded decimal and then he suddenly deleted the question. Admittedly the question was phrased in such a way that he came across looking foolish, and perhaps he was embarrassed, but I think there might be other people with the same notion, so I think it would be preferable not to delete it. Also, my answer was also deleted along with the question, boo hoo.

Comment: If the answers have upvotes or the question is locked, you can't delete it. Your posts do not belong to you ;)

Comment: My answer had one upvote I believe.

Comment: Sure? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Yes, fairly sure, but as the answer has been deleted I can't go back and check it. The question was deleted only a few minutes after I'd answered it. The question was "Why doesn't Intel have (binary coded decimal) in their chips?", where the questioner hadn't got the name of it, and I answered him with a short answer and a link to Wikipedia.