# How can I delete my question?

Tags: support, questions, self-delete

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)
>   [How can I delete my post on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow)

Hello, now I am asking a second stupid question. And I need to delete both of them.

Comment: i think there is a delete option under your post... beside the 'edit' ... etc

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean

Comment: @janaspage the whole account system has had quite some changes since I added that previous comment... it's not relevant anymore, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 35):

There's a delete underneath the tags to the question that is visible to you if you asked it.

However, you won't be able to delete a question if it has answers voted up by the community (or if you accepted one of those answers)

You can only delete it if you have non upvoted answers.

Comment: Wait, you can only delete if you have no answers at all or only delete if the answers you have have not been upvoted?

Comment: @User, if they are voted up -- you can delete the question if the answers have a score less than or equal to 0

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification, your statement "You can only delete it if you have no answers" confused me.

Comment: Also if you have a question that is down voted, and you delete it, then it appears to remove the negative reputation associated with that question.

Answer (score 11):

There's a delete underneath the tags to the question that is visible to you if you asked it.  It's subtle and missable.