# How to delete a post on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete my post on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow)

I am a noobie and asked a basic question, to which I did not know the answer.  But after being berated by some users for asking a "stupid question" I would like to delete the question how do I do this?

I did not realize how some stackoverflow users can be so mean, when someone is just trying to learn.

Comment: By the way, most people get more irritated by users not looking for answers for themselves first (as you've done here) than by people asking simple questions.

Comment: The fact that the "mean" SO user who commented on said question lost 3*2 rep seconds before you posted this question puzzles me a bit...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a candy store.

Answer (score 3):

Where you see "share | edit | flag" links below tags on questions there should also be a "delete" link.