# How do you delete a question from stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

How to delete a question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

There is a "delete" link below the tags. You can click it to delete your question. But you can not delete the question that contains answer(s).

You can delete your answer using same "delete" link.

See the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a `delete` link just below your post. Just click it to delete your post.

For more information, go through this **[link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25088/196352)**